# LDAP filter for single value in multivalue field

Tags: perl, filter, ldap

I'm trying to build a LDAP query that searches for groups that are owned (multivalued attribute) by a particular user and nobody else.

Simple Exp:

```
Group A: Owners [Bob, Joe, Bill]
Group B: Owners [Bob]
Group C: Owners [Carl]
```

Only group b should be returned by this query if I was looking for Bob. My current query pulls all groups where a named person is an owner then I'm using Perl to loop through the results and find what I need, but it seems a little inefficient. Any pointers or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share the code you've written so far, so we can offer specific advice.

Comment: There's no "specific" code to share, as this isn't a coding issue. The Perl usage is simply for filtering out results that I hoped the LDAP filter would do instead. The Perl piece is working perfectly. I was hoping more for a LDAP filter solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. There is no LDAP filter syntax that can possibly accomplish that. See [RFC 2254](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2254.txt). This is a very strange design. It doesn't map not LDAP can do at all.